# Bubblesort does not sort more than 254859 elements - Why?

Tags: c

Just the question! Why can it not sort more than 254859 elements?

Comment: Probably because it would take forever.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the answer will depend on how you've written your code.

Comment: Have you used Google to research it and couldn't find any hint about it mentioned in the Bubblesort descriptions? That's because it's your specific implementation that doesn't sort it. Show us your code, then we may be able to find your mistakes. Don't forget to tell us about your test data, and what specific error you get.

Answer (score 2):

It can, but:

- It takes forever
- You need to use data types that can hold enough elements.

Other than that, there is absolutely no reason why the algorithm itself would be limited to any particular input size.

Comment: ok, must be the data type, i've set it to int and not long! It doesnt take that long either considering its a 'bad' algorithm. Just 1 minute and 12 seconds! Meanwhile google seaarches through billions in less than a second...yikes!

Comment: @John it gets infinitely worse the larger the list is. Probably insertion sort is better for such a large list.